# How to customize the size of the action bar logo

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, toolbar

I am using a toolbar as an action bar I don't know how to change the size of the logo

```
private void setToolBar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_lang);
        }
    }
```

This is the XML

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@color/blueBack"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:logo="@drawable/logomch"
                android:paddingEnd="55dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

I can't upload images cause i's my first question, but the logo does't occupy the entire height of the action bar (70dp).
As a logo I am using a drawable like the hamburger type.

Thanks for any help, I didn't find an answer in previous posts

Comment: you can place views inside toolbar separately,put logo in imageview and set layout_height as match_parent ie 70 dp with 0 padding <Toolbar>.......<Imageview>...</toolbar>

Comment: Thanks for answer. That works to insert an image, but my problem is with the logo that is used to display the menu.
`getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_lang);`